# Gulp error throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: gulp, git-bash, node-modules

The whole gulp workflow was working fine until today i got this error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
  at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
  at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
  at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
  at ret.catch.module.exports.promise (C:\Users\user\desktop\workflows\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\exec-buffer\node_modules\execa\index.js:139:26)
  at C:\Users\user\desktop\workflows\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\exec-buffer\index.js:35:15
```

Adding the gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
       gutil = require('gulp-util'),
       coffee = require('gulp-coffee'),
       concat = require('gulp-concat'),
       browserify = require('gulp-browserify'),
       compass = require('gulp-compass'),
       connect = require('gulp-connect'),
       gulpif = require('gulp-if'),
       uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
       minifyHTML = require('gulp-minify-html'),
       jsonMinify = require('gulp-jsonminify'),
       imageMin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
       pngCrush = require('imagemin-pngcrush');

var env,
       coffeeSources,
       jsSources,
       sassSources,
       htmlSources,
       jsonSources,
       outputDir,
       sassStyle;

env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';

if(env === 'development'){
    outputDir = 'builds/development/';
    sassStyle="expanded";
}else{
    outputDir = 'builds/production/';
    sassStyle = 'compressed';
}

coffeeSources = ['components/coffee/tagline.coffee'];
jsSources = [
        'components/scripts/rclick.js',
        'components/scripts/pixgrid.js',
        'components/scripts/tagline.js',
        'components/scripts/template.js'
       ];
sassSources = ['components/sass/style.scss'];
 htmlSources = [outputDir + '*.html'];
 jsonSources = [outputDir + '*.json'];



gulp.task('coffee',function(){
    gulp.src(coffeeSources)
    .pipe(coffee({bare:true})
      .on('error',gutil.log))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('components/scripts'))
});

gulp.task('js',function(){
    gulp.src(jsSources)
    .pipe(concat('script.js'))
    .pipe(browserify())
    .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', uglify()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + 'js'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('compass', function(){
    gulp.src(sassSources)
    .pipe(compass({
        sass:'components/sass',
        image:'builds/development/images',
        style:sassStyle
    })
      .on('error',gutil.log))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + 'css'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('watch',function(){
    gulp.watch(coffeeSources,['coffee']);
    gulp.watch(jsSources,['js']);
    gulp.watch('components/sass/*.scss',['compass']);
    gulp.watch('builds/development/*.html',['html']);
    gulp.watch('builds/development/js/*.json',['json'])
    gulp.watch('builds/development/images/**/*.*',['json']);
});

gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: outputDir,
    livereload: true
  });
});

gulp.task('html', function(){
    gulp.src('builds/development/*.html')
    .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', minifyHTML()))
    .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', gulp.dest(outputDir)))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('images', function(){
    gulp.src('builds/development/images/**/*.*')
    .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', imageMin({
        progressive:true

    })))
    .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', gulp.dest(outputDir+ 'images')))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('json', function(){
    gulp.src('builds/development/js/*.json')
    .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', jsonMinify()))
    .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', gulp.dest('builds/production/js')))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
})


gulp.task('default',['html','json','coffee','js','compass','images','connect','watch'])
```

I am running Git Bash on windows. I saw some other SO questions related as well but couldn't make it work. Can someone help here?

Comment: Please show us your gulpfile.

Comment: Added @Vito....

Comment: Does the error appear in both environments?

Comment: I checked it for dev coz I had to work in it. But error hampers everything.

Comment: Please take a look if there is a file in `builds/development/images/**/*.*` which is not an image.

Comment: By the way: in the `watch` task you execute the wrong task (`json`) if an image has changed.

Comment: They are all images only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135357/discussion-between-vito-and-aakash-thakur).